# How to create an instance variable in one activity Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, variables, instance-variables

So this seems like an odd question, but there's something I'm not understanding about Android Studio (I just started working with it).

If I want to create a variable in an activity, and then access it within different methods in my activity, I should be able to do that, right?
For instance, consider the following code:

```java
public class bakers extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Bunz bunz;

    BigDecimal baker1Cost = BigDecimal.valueOf(20); //cost of baker1

    BigDecimal baker1Bunz = BigDecimal.valueOf(.1); //number of bunz produced by each baker1
    TextView baker1CostText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baker1Cost);
    TextView baker1Owned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baker1Owned);
    TextView baker1BunzText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baker1Bunz);
    TextView bunzCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bunzCount3);
    TextView moneyCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moneyCount3);

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {


        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bakers);

        bunz = Bunz.getInstance();



        bunzCount.setText("Bunz: " + bunz.getBunz());


        moneyCount.setText("Money: " + bunz.getMoney());


        baker1BunzText.setText(baker1Bunz.toPlainString());


        baker1CostText.setText("Cost: " + (baker1Cost));


        baker1Owned.setText("Owned: " + bunz.getBaker1());


    }
...
```

In this code, I try to *declare and initialize* a bunch of variable before my onResume() method, but this doesn't work. I've found that I can *declare* variables before the onResume() method, but then for instance if I want to update the value of these variables in the onResume() method, that's fine, but if I want to access that variable in another method, such as onClick, I can't do that, and have to redefine the variables.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? In essence, my question boils down to this: I want to have an instance variable for *one* activity (not throughout all activities) that I can access and modify anywhere within the activity.

EDIT: It seems as thought initializing and declaring variables before the onResume method works with things like ints, but I can only *declare* things like Buttons and Textviews - is there any way I can get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not initialize your variables in the `onCreate` method of your Activity? [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc) you can get an unterstanding of the activity lifecycle.

Comment: If I initialize them there, will I have access to them in the other methods in the activity?

Comment: Edit: So it appears, based on that documentation, that initializing variables in the onCreate method would create instance variables, but does this also apply to onResume?

Comment: You have used the method `findViewById` outside of the callback functions, which will only work after you set the layout of the activity (See `setContentView()` in `onCreate` method in the docs). You should use `setContentView()` inside onCreate since it is called before `onResume`. After that you can initialize your views using `findViewById`